# psql previous created functions disappeared after quit

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

Here are the steps and problems I meet in linux environment:

0. I ran `psql -d mimic -U postgres -W` to log in `psql`
1. I ran `\i postgres-function.sql` and use `\df` to display a list of functions. It does display functions I want under the proper schema
2. I ran `\q` to quit the `psql`
3. I ran `psql -d mimic -U postgres -W` to log in `psql`, then ran `\df` again. However, it displays an empty table. The previously stored functions automatically disappeared.

The reason I would like to `\q` in the `psql` because I want to run the `.sh` script after creating the functions. Could someone tell the reason why the functions created before disappeared? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-BASE-FUNCTIONS

I connected to a 9.6.22 server (not as "postgres"),
and defined `one()` as in the example.
I could SELECT from it, and see it with `\df`

Upon disconnecting and re-connecting,
I could still SELECT from it, and see it with `\df`

I connected to an 11.10 server and obtained identical results.

tl;dr: Cannot repro the reported problem.

Perhaps you connected as a user (-U postgres) that lacks write permission for new functions in the `public` schema?
Or a TEMPORARY table is involved, one which DROPs upon TCP disconnect?

You were rather vague on the contents of `postgres-function.sql`.
It seems like the details would be germane
if we want to get to the bottom of this mystery.

EDIT

Ok, thanks for the particulars.
The biggest difference seemed to be PLPGSQL.
I tried defining a simple function from the docs:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(f1 int) RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
  f1 int;
BEGIN
  RETURN f1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Upon re-connecting I could still use it with SELECT and `\df`

And then I noticed this detail in the [source code](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/main/mimic-iii/concepts/postgres-functions.sql#L5):

```
SET search_path TO mimiciii;
```

You are not creating `REGEXP_EXTRACT()`,
not creating `public.REGEXP_EXTRACT()`.
No, not by a long shot.

You are creating `mimiciii.REGEXP_EXTRACT()`.

The `\i` command made the search path take effect
for the rest of your session.
When you start a **new** session,
you will need to issue **another** search path directive
if you wish to refer to functions by their "short" names.
Alternatively, you can choose to use a "long" name
with SELECT or `\df`

Comment: Hi @J_H, thank you for your reply. The attributes for the user are Superuser, Create role, Create DB. The `postgres-function.sql` can be found in https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/main/mimic-iii/concepts/postgres-functions.sql

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply@J_H. I tried ```\df mimiciiii``` and still returns an empty table, after creating the functions and starting a new session. Not sure why those functions are not saved.

Comment: Well, you want a trailing `.` dot on `\df mimiciiii.` right? Which is just like querying `\df mimiciiii.*`. The command you showed is looking for `\df public.mimiciiii()`, I believe.